# calling function inside script tag not working

Tags: javascript, html

i have created an automated slideshow which should change the picture after every 2 secs;
i call the function changeSlide() at first then it should recursively call itself using the function setTimeout. but this doesn't work when page is first started or the page is refreshed.

but when i click on the button it starts working.

```
let slideIndex = 0;

    changeSlide();

    function changeSlide(){             
        slideIndex++;

        let images = document.getElementsByClassName('image');      
        for (let i = 0; i<images.length;i++){
            images[i].style.display="none";
        }

        if (slideIndex>= images.length){
            slideIndex = 0;
        }

        images[slideIndex].style.display = "block"; 
        setTimeout(changeSlide,2000);

    }
```

This is my html code.

```
<div class="w3-display-container w3-content">
        <img class="image" src="city.jpg" style="width: 100%;height:500px;" >
        <img class="image" src="profile.png" style="width: 100%; height:500px;display:none;" >
        <img class="image" src="img_girl.jpg" style="width: 100%;height:500px; display:none;" >

    </div>
    <button onClick="changeSlide()">Click Me</button>
```

i want my slideshow to start as soon as i start my page.

Comment: change `images[slideIndex].style.display = "block";` to 
`if(images[slideIndex])images[slideIndex].style.display = "block";` or place your script tag after html. it seems your code executed before tags loaded

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of `changeSlide();` do `window.onload=changeSlide;` that way you make sure the DOM exists when calling the function

Comment: thanks this worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You currently seem to not have any code that tells your page to run the function when it's loaded. Try adding the following to your body tag:

```
<body onload="changeSlide()">
    <!-- your other HTML code here -->
</body>
```

Comment: `You currently seem to not have any code that tells your page to run the function when it's loaded ` he calls the function just on the line before he declares the function, not nice, but he calls it

Comment: Read over that. As others suggested, his code should work if the JS is placed after the HTML, though I'd recommend removing that line and using my solution so code placement isn't an issue

Answer (score 0):

You should call `changeSlide` when browser has parsed your HTML markup, so it can access HTML elements. You have some options to make this work correctly.

1. Place your JS code after your HTML markup (After the `<div>` element containing images). Or just call `changeSlide` after it:

```html
<script>
    let slideIndex = 0;
    function changeSlide(){
        ...
    }
</script>

<div class="w3-display-container w3-content">
    ...
</div>

<script>
    changeSlide();
</script>
```

2. Run `changeSlide` after page load using `DOMContentLoaded` event:

```
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function(event){
    changeSlide();
});

// Or just:

window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', changeSlide);
```

Comment: 1.Place your JS code after your HTML markup. Or just call changeSlide after HTML: this doesn't work 2. run changeSlide after page load works

Comment: @deadpool I have tested both options and they work. `changeSlide` must be defined before calling it. I updated my answer.

Comment: it works if i add <script>changeSlide();</script> just before </body> but if i put it just after the <body> then it doesn't work.

Comment: @deadpool Yes, as I said, It works if you put `<script>changeSlide();</script>` after `<div>...</div>`.